# React-firebase I would like to fetch a data from another collection like RDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch a field from another collection.
There are two collections on my firestore.
Project and Users.
Project has documents. Each document has usersId(doc ids of users)

I tried to get fields from Overs.

However as far as I can see, it got "promise" data.

How can I get a certain userName by userId from a project?

```
const Summary = ({project}) => {

    const userName = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(project.userId).get();
    console.log(userName);


    return (
        <div>
    {userName}
        </div>
    )

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `get()` method returns a promise so you'll need wait until it's resolved. Try refactoring the code like this:

```
const Summary = ({ project }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const snap = await firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(project.userId).get();
      console.log(snap.data());
    }
    getData()
  }, [])


  return ( 
    <div>{data.userName}</div>
  )

}
```